# Custom "add to cart" button throws wrong error in PrestaShop

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to have an "Add to Cart" button on a custom page (not product page), basically a button that I can pass a certain product ID and calls the ajax-cart.js function "add".

Now, I've tried this code:

```
<a class="exclusive_small ajax_add_to_cart_button" title="{l s='Add to cart'}" onclick="ajaxCart.add(26, null, false, null, 1, null)">{l s='Add to cart'}</a>
```

but, though it **does** add the product with the specified ID (26 in that case) to the cart, it also fires an alert box with 2 errors: *Product not found*, and *This product is no longer available.*

I've managed to find the piece of code that handles these errors, in the CartController.php:

```
protected function processChangeProductInCart()
{
    $mode = (Tools::getIsset('update') && $this->id_product) ? 'update' : 'add';

    if ($this->qty == 0)
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Null quantity.', !Tools::getValue('ajax'));
    elseif (!$this->id_product)
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Product not found', !Tools::getValue('ajax'));

    $product = new Product($this->id_product, true, $this->context->language->id);
    if (!$product->id || !$product->active)
    {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This product is no longer available.', !Tools::getValue('ajax'));
        return;
    }
```

but I don't understand how it works, and why the errors show when it's otherwise working as it should.

Have I done something wrong, is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom page first you have to get product id and the product attribute id then on the click of your button you have to submit these values to your front controller(which you make) and in that controller you get these ids and add to a new cart. You have to code like:

Create your tpl file->

abc.tpl

```
        <input type="button" name="vss_add_to_cart" value="{l s='Add to cart' mod='your_module_name'}" class="vss_btn1" id="vss_add_to_cart"  style="background:{$background|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'};color:{$text|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'};border:{$border|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'};"/>
```

Now you have to write some script for the click of that buuton in same file:

```
 </script>
 $( "#vss_add_to_cart" ).one( "click", function() {
        var id_product_attribute = document.getElementById('idCombination').value;
        var id_product = document.getElementById('product_page_product_id').value;
        var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_wanted').value;
        $.post(
                '{$link|escape:'quotes':'UTF-8'}',
                {
                    id: id_product,
                    ipa: id_product_attribute,
                    qty: quantity
                },
        function (data) {
            window.location.replace(data);
        }
        );
    });
    </script>
```

In that the {$link} is that where you want to get values, actually for that you have to create a controller in your module folder and in that a front folder like:

```
C:\wamp\www\prestashop\modules\oneclickcheckout\controllers\front
```

now in that you have to make a file your_module_name.php and write the code:

your_module_name.php

```
class OneclickcheckoutOneclickcheckoutModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

    public function initContent()
    {

        $qty = Tools::getValue('qty');
        $id_product = Tools::getValue('id');
        $id_product_attribute = Tools::getValue('ipa');

            $this->context->cart->add();
            if ($this->context->cart->id) {
                $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int) $this->context->cart->id;
            }
            $this->context->cart->updateQty($qty, $id_product, $id_product_attribute);
            $link = $this->context->link->getPageLink('order');
            echo $link;
            die;
        } 
}
```

Then a new cart is added in your database and correponding to that cart product details are also inserted.I hope this would help you.